# Как проверить что какими тестами покрыто?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день. Перешел мне легаси код .Более менеее читабельный .Хочу проверить его на наличие покрытых и не покрытых тестов.Как это сделать в аднроие ?Испоьзую Андроид студио

Comment: перейдите на вкладку с тестами, у вас загорится кнопочка, плей такой с палочками, "run 'test' with Coverage". Этот run будет учитывать покрытие.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei  ооо классно что это есть внедренно в андроид студио

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать плагины:

1. [jacoco](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) покажет вам какой код покрыт тестами. Мне понравился возможностью генерации html отчета. [Вот пример такого отчета.](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/coverage/)
2. [pitest](http://pitest.org/) плагин мутационного тестирования. Покрытие может быть 100%, но при этом ничего не проверять. Этот плагин немного меняет исходных код и ждет, чтобы хоть 1 тест упал. Если ни один тест не падает - значит место уязвимо. Так же генерирует html отчет.

Answer (score 3):

Перейдите в папку src / test / java и щелкните правой кнопкой мыши. Затем выберите **Run Tests in java with Coverage**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]